# What's the difference of LastWriteTime and LastAccessTime

Tags: c#, windows, operating-system

I have a bug on while trying access files ordered by LastWriteTime and trying to understand the difference of LastAccessTime

I tried to look for answer for the difference but didn't find any.

LastWriteTime:
Gets or sets the time when the current file or directory was last written to.
lastaccesstime:
Gets or sets the time the current file or directory was last accessed.

What's the difference of LastWriteTime and LastAccessTime?

Comment: access could also be a reading of the file or directory

Comment: `written to` and `accessed`.  these words should be understood and then you will have answered your own question

Comment: Write is the last Write Time while Access could be either Read or Write.

Comment: I loaded a file using notepad++ but access time still remain as it used to be. Why doesn't the access changed?

Comment: [This](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/9cd06480-984b-4847-a425-92f1928d6d55/lastaccesstime-file-property?forum=winserver8gen) might have something to do with it. Apparently, updating `LastAccessTime` is by default disabled. I have verified on my computer using `fsutil behavior query disablelastaccess` and on my computer, it's disabled. That begs the question then as to *when* does it actually gets updated. Just reading the file doesn't update.

Comment: `LastWriteTime: Gets or sets the time when the current file or directory was last written to. lastaccesstime: Gets or sets the time the current file or directory was last accessed.` It pretty much answers it there. One is when it was **written to**. One is when it was **accessed**. But see the answers below to see why "accessed" is not super helpful.

Comment: Have you read https://superuser.com/questions/251263/the-last-access-date-is-not-changed-even-after-reading-the-file-on-windows-7 ? Please do so.

Comment: Now I know the difference of both write and access (and that access is off, as default)

Comment: @mjwills - Thanks, that does clear things up a bit more. Assuming that `DisableLastAccess` is enabled: what does the LastAccessTime actually represents? Time of creation?

Answer (score 4):

In the default configuration, Windows doesn't keep track of the last access times for directories.

You can turn this on using:

```
fsutil behavior set disablelastaccess 0
```

However, this may affect system performance

Info: 
Disables (1) or enables (0) updates to the Last Access Time stamp on each directory when directories are listed on an NTFS volume.

You must restart your computer for this parameter to take effect.

Comment: Thank you but I don't need to turn it on, I wanted to know why does the previous developer used LastWriteTime instead of LastAccessTime

Comment: cannot confirm, what may be thought by previous developer .May be LastAccessTime does not changes/reflects the updated value as disablelastaccess by default is in OFF mode therefore LastWriteTime was used .

Comment: Just to add a something for consideration. The LastAccessTime might not be being updated by the filesystem... It might be some other bespoke service/app where a developer might be setting it for some deranged reason.